# ctypes import not working on python 2.5

Tags: python, macos, ctypes, python-2.5

I am trying to import ctypes, and I am using Python 2.5.5 installed using macports (on Mac OS X 10.6).

I get an error saying "ImportError: No module named _ctypes" (see details below). As I understand it ctypes is supposed to come preinstalled for python 2.5. Any suggestions?

thanks,
Saurabh

Error details:

```
$ python
Python 2.5.5 (r255:77872, Nov 30 2010, 00:05:47) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5659)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/ctypes/\_\_init\_\_.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: No module named _ctypes
```

Update: I checked the `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload` directory based no Ned's reply. There is no _ctypes.so file, however the two related files that are there are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  136176 Nov 30 00:07 _ctypes_failed.so
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel   26160 Nov 30 00:05 _ctypes_test.so
```

Does this mean I need to reinstall ctypes?

Update 2: Reinstalling python 2.5 solved the problem. Not quite sure what caused the original problem.

Comment: Wow i'm i didn't know people still used 2.5.

Comment: @Rook people still use Python 2.4.x, too.

Comment: @Rook on Red hat, CentOS, some other server distros it's still common to have 2.5 or even 2.4. Google doesn't use anything past 2.5 (in fact, to develop App Engine you have to target 2.5).

Comment: It probably has something to do with a path variable. The resolution on [this post](http://community.activestate.com/forum/import-ctypes-fails) was to delete an `APPDATA` environment variable. Perhaps that solves your problem?

Comment: @marcog I don't have any environment variable called APPDATA. @Rook I need python2.5 because of some dependencies. Import ctypes actually does work fine on my system for python2.6.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler wow talk about garbage distros.  Support for 2.5  was dropped 3 years ago.

Comment: @Rook, @Rafe RHEL 4 uses Python 2.3 and is still actively supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a file permission problem.  I don't have a MacPorts Python 2.5 installation handy but, based on a MacPorts Python 2.6, there should be a file something like this:

```
$ cd /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5
$ cd ./lib/python2.5/lib-dynload/
$ ls -l _ctypes.so 
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  151536 Oct  8 00:26 _ctypes.so*
```

If not, update your question with the results of an `ls -l` of the `lib-dynload` directory above.

Update: based on your additional information, the presence of `_ctypes_failed.so` indicates that the building of `_ctypes` failed during the build and installation of Python 2.5.  Try reinstalling it with verbose mode to see what the failure is:

```
$ port sudo selfupdate
$ port -v upgrade --force python25
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest Mac OS X ships with Python 2.6. Try using that instead of macports. Importing ctypes works already on my system.

```
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install libffi, then rebuild Python.